# Haskell IO can't get the list to loop around a menu function

Tags: haskell, io

I'm currently making a text based menu system in haskell. I have made a data type called Book where each function edits the list and returns it. However I cannot work out how to make a menu part work where it can edit this list and recurse back around.

Example on what I'm stuck on
menu works,
add a book to the list,
menu then needs to reload the menu so I can display the books with the new addition.

example of menu

```
menu:: [Book] -> [IO]
menu books = do
  str <- getLine
  let selectNum = (read str :: Int)
  case selectNum of
     1 -> let sd = addNewBookIO books 
     2 -> displayAllBooksFromYear books
```

example of adding a new book

```
addNewBookIO :: [Book] -> IO [Book]
addNewBookIO films =
  do putStr "Film name: " 
     filmTitle <- getLine
     putStr "List all cahr in the Book (separated by commas): "
     cast <- addToStringArray []
     putStr "Year of Realese in the UK: "
     year <- getLine
     let test = (read year :: Int)
     putStr "List all the fans(separated by commas): "
     fans <- addToStringArray [] 
     putStrLn "Your Book has been added"
     let bookList = addbookFilm (Film bookTitle cast test fans) films
     return bookList
```

Any help would be grateful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the moment your type signature for `menu` doesn't make any sense. Do you mean something like this?

```
menu :: [Book] -> IO [Book]
```

If so, then you could define it to be

```
menu books = do
  str <- getLine
  case read str of
    1 -> do books' <- addNewBookIO books             -- add a new book, then loop
            menu books'
    2 -> displayAllBooksFromYear books >> menu books -- display books, then loop
    3 -> return books                                -- quit
```

This reads a string from the user, and then either adds a new book, displays the current list of books or ends the loop, returning the list of books.

**Edit:** The `>>` operator sequences two operations together. The combination `a >> b` means "do `a`, then do `b`".

The following two pieces of code are exactly equivalent (in fact, the first one is just syntactic sugar for the second)

```
do displayAllBooksFromYear books
   menu books
```

and

```
displayAllBooksFromYear books >> menu books
```

Hope that helps clear things up.

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you. Can you just tell me what "'" means after Books in case 1? and what >> does?

Comment: The `'` has no special meaning. It's a legal character in a variable name in Haskell, so `books'` is just a new variable. I could have called it `books2` instead. I'm about to edit the question to clarify the meaning of `>>`.